# c# initialize a class var x = new class()

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var x= new Class();
```

I would like to create `x[1], x[2]..`and so on. How can I do that?

EDIT:

I have

```
 static Main()
 { 
    var x = new Class();
 }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense... could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean an array of Class?

Comment: You want a class indexer? So you can do `x[0] = "value";` ?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use array initializer syntax:

```
var x = new Class[] 
{ 
    new Class(), // x[0]
    new Class(), // x[1]
    new Class()  // x[2]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to make an array, which you can do as follows:

```
Class[] x = new Class[3];
x[0] = new Class();
x[1] = new Class();
x[2] = new Class();
```